# Doctype with goquery

Tags: go, goquery

Is there any possibility to retrieve document doctype with goquery?

I've tried several things, but any worked. I suppose that it is possible, because NodeName func has switch with "html.DoctypeNode" case.

That code didn't find doctype:

```
doc.Find("~").Each(func(_ int, item *goquery.Selection) {
    fmt.Println(goquery.NodeName(item))
})
```

Comment: What happens if you use `doc.Each()` directly (without the `Find`) instead of using the non-matching `Find("~")`?

Comment: I receive string "#document"

Comment: If it takes in the doctype element at all, it should be the first of two children of `#document` (the second being the `html` element).

Comment: But it's not:  doc.Each(func(_ int, item *goquery.Selection) {
  fmt.Println(goquery.NodeName(item))
 }) -> returns #document only

Comment: Right. Look at the *children* of #document.

Comment: Unfortunately still nothing: fmt.Println(goquery.NodeName(item.Children()))

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like there is a reliable way to [retrieve the doctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/doctype) using either jQuery itself (in the web browser) or [goquery](https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) on the backend.